# How to use editor.action.joinLines in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As the title says, in [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_sublime-text-compatibility) you can use the `editor.action.joinLines` to join different lines of text to one single line? Being an editor noob, the question is how? How do I map this command to a key board short cut, or what mouse actions do I need to do after selecting the said text, to get two different lines as one single line? Specifically I am working on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To join several lines you have to select them first (you can read more about various ways of selecting text in the [vs code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor)) and then invoke the `Join Lines` command. As a result, all text from the second and next lines will be appended to the end of first lines.

[image]

You can invoke the `Join Lines` command either from the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on macOS and typing `Join Lines` or by pressing the assigned shortcut - <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure your own key bindings by clicking File>Preferences>Keyboardshortcuts on Vscode main menu.
There you can bind the command **joinLines** to your prefered Keyboard keys as shown in this link.
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEeAr.png)